# How to pass an auth api key as a header for every page request in React?

Tags: reactjs, http, react-router

I basically have a back end api that I'm hitting with a React SPA. 
I have a username password auth that assigns a key to the user when the client is authenticated. The key needs to be passed as a header on every http request.

I want to be able to pass this authentication header on EVERY api request.

Is there an easy way to do this? I.e. someway to have a top level React component that handles passing this on every page request?

I assume this is a common problem for SPA and the solution is out there.
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: store your key anywhere (a store / a singleton object / the state of the top level component / ..) and use it everytime

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is to store the key in `localStorage`. So, when you get the key, do something like:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', key);
```

Then, you can retrieve it:

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not related with React or react-router. It depends on the HTTP request library -- after authenticated, all you need to do is **config the library and make it send the `key` header every time**.

If jQuery is used to send the API request, the code would be:

```
// get key from successful authentication response
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr) {
  jqxhr.setRequestHeader('KEY', key);
});
```

If axios is used to send the API request, the code would be:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['KEY'] = key;
```

If something else is used to send the API request, you can check the library's document and make the same config operation.